# How can I count a list of tuples from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, count, tuples, n-gram

I have 2 list of tuples in Python:

1. `ListA` is made up of tuples containing all the possible sequence of n
   bytes.
   For example 1-byte sequences: `[(0,), (1,), (2,), ... (255,)]`
2. `ListB` is made up of tuples containing random sequence of n
   bytes.
   For example: `[[(127,), (69,), (76,), ...]`

I would need to count every possible byte sequence even if it occurs 0 times. I am trying to do this with `collections.Counter` but I don't know how to make it so it counts 0 occurrences, too.

I am looking for an efficient way since `ListA` can be large depending on the length of the byte sequences (1 byte sequence = 256 values, 2 byte sequences = 65,536 values ...), and even `ListB` can be larger depending on how many tuples it contains.

Is there a way to utilize `Counter` function with the possibility to count the 0 occurrences or what is the best way to iterate over the 2 lists, compare and count the occurrences?

Comment: Count every possible byte sequence in what list? What have you tried?

Comment: So, why don't you just use: `Counter(ListB)` and assume all other values count as `0`?

Comment: Also note: `Counter` has a function `.get(key, default)` which returns `default` if it doesn't exist in the counter.

Comment: I don't understand the intended purpose of `ListA`, or why you think "iterating over the two lists" and "comparing" is going to be helpful for counting the occurrences. I also don't understand what you mean by "with the possibility to count the 0 occurrences". There also aren't any occurrences of `"hi mom"` in `ListB`; should we explicitly record that as well?

Comment: `collections.Counter` is dictionary *subclass* not a function. After creating one, you can initialize the counts of *specific* keys in it to zero in-place via `my_counter.update(dict.fromkeys(('k1', 'k2', 'k3), 0))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a count dictionary when you create the lists and fill the dictionary with all of the values that you need.
An example for this:

```py
import random

listA = []
listB = []
count = {}
for i in range(256):
    listA.append((i,))
    listB.append((random.randint(0, 255),))
    count[i] = 0
for i in listB:
    count[i[0]] += 1
```